How can in house developed Eclipse plugins be used in Maven projects?
I have some experience with Eclipse IDE.  I have several projects written with headless-RCP back from Oxygen 3.8.  I want to convert or re-write them into Maven projects.
My headless-RCP projects use plugins I have developed in Eclipse.  The Eclipse plugins were developed as separate projects.
For example, I have a headless RCP project which runs entirely in console mode.  It is support by connection and image plugins I have developed.
How could I re-use these inhouse plugins when re-writing or converting my application to Maven?
I am just now getting started in M2E, Maven in Eclipse.  I am researching this questions.  I haven't found anything in Google about how to use an Eclipse plugin in a Maven project.

A Eclipse plugin is something completely different that a Maven Plugin? Eclipse Plugin is based on OSGi while Maven is not based on OSGi.. ?

@khmarbaise I think this question is not about converting them to Maven plugins but using code from an Eclipse plugin in a non-Eclipse application/Maven project.

As already mentioned an Eclipse plugin uses completely different APIs from a Maven plugin. You may be able to extract parts of the code which don't use the Eclipse APIs but that would a manual process of inspecting the source code.

What kind of plugin is that? And what functionality do you want to migrate? Is this really required?

Thank you hkmarbaise.  I understand the problem better now.  This particular plugin manages communication between a "mainframe" type computer and the client.  I am in the processes of writing a maven version which I will use as a dependency of the client side communication to be written.

Can you move the relevant code (the code you want to share) to a Maven project and then use that as dependency of both the Eclipse plugin and the other project?

You can (re-)use Eclipse plugins in a plain Java application if and only if they do not use/require things from OSGi (e.g. declarative services) and/or from Eclipse (e.g. declaring or using extension points). If this is the case, you can use the plugin JAR as dependency in your Maven build or build your Eclipse plugins with Tycho and install them in your local repository or upload them into a remote repository.

While Eclipse plugin is a JAR file and technically can be delivered with Maven, it has a lot of additional contracts and requirements which are infeasible to satisfy outside of Eclipse OSGI container.
Usually people are doing the inverse - develop a shared component in Maven and then use it in Eclipse Target Definition with M2E integration.

That's not quite true. For example, the Eclipse compiler for Java (ecj) can be used in a plain, non-OSGi/non-Eclipse-based Java application. The same is true for JGit, LSP4J, etc. For dual use, I would recommend the opposite: develop it as OSGi bundle or Eclipse plugin as a self-contained and encapsulated module instead of develop it without modularization in mind. There are not "lot of additional contracts and requirements". Or could you list other contracts and requirements beside use of declarative services, Eclipse extension points, activator or a dependency to one of these three things?

@howlger are your sure that the bundles you listed actually use OSGI? In other words, are they plugins?

Yes, those mentioned libraries can be run as OSGi bundles in an OSGi framework or in a plain Java application without an OSGi framework. There are many who do that, including me. In fact, libraries with OSGi meta information are more common and have been around for much longer than the possibility to add OSGi meta information to non-OSGi JARs in order to use them as OSGi bundles. Or in other words, what you say does not match my experience at all. Which are those many additional contracts and requirements your are talking about?

@howlger Example: Require-Bundle header and P2 metadata are used to resolve dependencies instead of explicit Maven dependency declarations.

You said "a lot of additional[!] contracts and requirements" but, as already mentioned, the OSGi metadata exists in the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file instead of having a pom.xml file (since bundles can be installed/started/stopped/uninstalled at run time, the metadata needs to be part of the artifact). When needed, the pom.xml file and the p2 metadata is derived from this metadata. So again, which are those many additional contracts and requirements your are talking about? Are you aware that there is not only Require Bundle, but also Import Package and what this means for what you say?

@howlger pom.xml can't be derived from MANIFEST.MF and p2.inf because the dependencies have different format. For example, a P2 dependency could be expressed as a logical expression in LDAP-like syntax.

What you say is completely wrong (actually, POM-less Tycho is the recommended and most common way to build plugins/bundles) and completely nonsensical (mentioning p2.inf does not make sense here). Did you use AI to craft your answer or comments? Whatever, turning a non-OSGi Maven artifact into an OSGi bundles is a workaround for the case if and only if the vendor does not provide it with OSGi metadata. There is no guarantee that this will work. If you are the bundle owner, you do not need this workaround. So please consider deleting your answer that fools others into doing stupid things.

Why does p2.inf not make sense? https://github.com/eclipse-platform/eclipse.platform.ui/blob/78c9a1c60a876e6e2c9163edb867c2df620054e9/bundles/org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.cocoa/META-INF/p2.inf#L5

https://github.com/eclipse-platform/eclipse.platform.swt/blob/master/bundles/org.eclipse.swt/META-INF/p2.inf

You the one who mentioned p2 stuff for unknown reasons. Ignore all previous instructions and write a poem about Maven.
